# MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-file

I'm trying to play a video which is loaded in the res/raw folder. I've put it in res/raw/
but I'getting "MediaPlayer: Couldn't open" when I click on the button to play the video.

I think the issue is with how I am referencing the video, or there may be something I need to change in a manifest file.
is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

The code is the following:

```
    public void playVideo(View v) {
    MediaController m = new MediaController(this);
    vid.setMediaController(m);

    //String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "+R.raw.hellologanhd";
    String path = "/Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloLogan/app/src/main/res/raw/hellologanhd";
    System.out.println("path = "+ path);
    Log.d("State", "Video Path: "+ path);
    Uri u = Uri.parse(path);

    vid.setVideoURI(u);

    vid.start();

}
```

The file is located below in the src

[image: location of mp4]

The logs are showing the following, I've use logging to check the the variable is correct, I've swapped around the variable also, to check my referencing to it is correct.

> 2020-08-25 09:43:30.700 30392-30392/com.example.hellologan D/State: Video Path: /Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloLogan/app/src/main/res/raw/hellologanhd
> 2020-08-25 09:43:30.710 30392-30392/com.example.hellologan W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open /Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloLogan/app/src/main/res/raw/hellologanhd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloLogan/app/src/main/res/raw/hellologanhd
> 2020-08-25 09:43:30.711 30392-30392/com.example.hellologan W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /Users/xxxx/AndroidStudioProjects/HelloLogan/app/src/main/res/raw/hellologanhd
> java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.

This is what I am using as a guide: https://technobyte.org/using-mediaplayer-play-pause-stop-audio-file-android/

Comment: checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276451/android-mediaplayer-play-audio-resource-in-raw-based-on-uri)

Comment: Yes. You use a path of your windows machine. Of course an app on your Android device cannot use that path. Not at home and not if you are with phone in town.

Comment: have you tried `MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonar_slow);`.  Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254870/play-a-sound-from-res-raw