# Media player to return file from res folder

Tags: java, android

If someone can help me with this problem:
I'm trying to get the song from res folder in this method

```
    private void playSound(String file) {
        Context context = binding.playBtn.getContext();
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int sound_id = resources.getIdentifier(file,"raw",
                context.getPackageName());
       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,sound_id);
       mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Then to call this method here

```
    public void bind(CalmScreenItem calmScreenItem) {
        binding.mainText.setText(calmScreenItem.mainText);
        binding.subtext.setText(calmScreenItem.subtext);
        binding.itemImg.setImageDrawable(getImage(calmScreenItem.imgUrl));
        binding.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playSound(calmScreenItem.soundUrl);
            }
        });
    }
```

Then finally call in the main fragment in the list**

```
private List<CalmScreenItem> getItems() {
    List<CalmScreenItem> calmScreenItems = new ArrayList<>();
    calmScreenItems.add(new CalmScreenItem(getString(R.string.main_item1),getString(R.string.sub_item1),"guide","free.mp3"));
    calmScreenItems.add(new CalmScreenItem(getString(R.string.main_item2),getString(R.string.sub_item2),"mindfull","mindfull.mp3"));


    return calmScreenItems;
}
```

The output should be when clicked on button to play different sound from the res folder

Can someone please help me! Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the way you are fetching the files

YOu would need to use an `Uri` and pass that to the MediaPlayer for it to be able to play your music . Also store y our audio files in raw subdirectory

For eg:

```
Uri mediaPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.filename);
try {
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), mediaPath);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ref : [StackOverflow questionon playing music from raw resource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24276451/13533028)